# Maven dependencies are downloaded but eclipse won't resolve them

Tags: eclipse, maven, compiler-errors, dependencies

A multi-module maven project will be buit successfully from the command line using `mvn clean install` and is loaded successfully in vscode without any compilation errors.

When the same project is opened in Eclipse (version Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0), Build id: 20220908-1902), I see compilation errors for dependencies not resolved for example:

```
The import com.ibm cannot be resolved
```

I tried everything to resolve this error, nothing worked, for example:

1. Update maven project
2. Project / Clean
3. Remove maven feature, delete the project, reimport, and convert back to maven

The strange thing is that if I delete the repository folder from `<user-home>\m2.\repository` and make a simple change to any `pom.xml` file, the entire repository folder is downloaded. Also, I located the JAR file using VSCode (ctrl-click) and I can see the related JAR `logEnglish-1.0.jar` in the local .m2 repository folder `<user-home>\.m2\repository\logEnglish\logEnglish\1.0\logEnglish-1.0.jar`.

The problem is that only Eclipse is reporting compilation errors and a lot or maybe all of the maven dependencies are not resolved. This is also affecting the debugging option and it breaks due to such compilation errors.

Another thing I noticed is that the `Maven Dependencies` folder is not showing on the Project Explorer no in Package Explorer, but I can see `Maven Dependencies` entry in `Project Properties -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries`.

Please help resolve this issue so that I can clear the compilation errors in Eclipse.

---

## Update 1:

I created a simple parent/child pom with one inner module. I was able to reproduce the problem right away.

See attached snapshots for details.

The compile errors will show only when you open the parent project. If you open the inner module directly as a separate project, no compile errors will show and I can run and debug the project. However, if I try to debug the parent project, I will get a warning due to compile errors, and I can run the project only and only after I added the jar of the inner module to the `classpath` of the debug configuration. If I don't add the jar file, I will get this error `Error: Could not find or load main class training.FirstProjectClass`. The project is being built successfully using `mvn clean install` and that's why I can run the project. If I run `mvn clean` then I cannot run the parent project.

Also, notice how the maven dependencies folder will show if you open the inner project directly, but, it won't show if you open the parent project.

In addition, I noticed if I add the inner project to the `classpath` of the debug config then it works also without building the project and without generating the `jar` file using `mvn clean install`.

Based on the above, the problem boils down to:

> How we can resolve the dependencies of the inner modules when you open the project using the parent maven project?

If we can resolve the errors, then we can run without seeing the warning, and we have the assurance that the project is clear before running the `mvn clean install` command.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file somewhere? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't see `module-info.java` anywhere in the project folder. My next step was to create a simple multi-module maven project and see what was wrong. I have a feeling it's a nasty Eclipse issue. The funny thing is that it's working in vs code. I just remember that I deleted all the `test` project parts in `vscode` as they had compile errors. Could this be causing the compile errors in eclipse? How I can exclude such folders in Eclipse?

Comment: I do not suspect so, since in VS Code Java language support is under the hood Eclipse. Are you talking about Maven or Java modules? In both cases, each module must be a Java/Maven project of its own in Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, I have checked out the project for vscode and Eclipse in two separate folders. In vscode, it works without any problem.

Comment: @howlger Could you please check the update I added to the original question?

Comment: `training` is the parent project with the parent POM, right? Then it should not contain Java code and it should not be a Java project (nested Java projects does not make sense). In contrast, `project1` should be a Maven and Java project (on some screenshot it is, on some not).

Comment: @howlger Do you mean I am not supposed to open the source code of the inner modules from the parent project? And you mean that I am not supposed to launch the application from the parent project? I don't have any java code in the parent project. I am just trying to work with the project and its inner modules while they are loaded from the parent project. I figured out I can load the inner modules and switch to project presentations `Hierarchical` but it becomes confusing like hell. Is this issue due to Eclipse by Desing?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should import/open the project with the parent POM (in your example `training`) as regular project and the projects that are specified as modules in the parent POM, each as a separate Maven Java project (in your example `project1`). Having Java code in the parent project does not make sense. And there is also no concept of nested Java projects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250051/discussion-between-tarekahf-and-howlger).